# Is there a more efficient way to make a quiz and have two different outcomes based on if the answers are mostly yes/no?

Tags: c#, if-statement, console

This is a quiz that determines if the user likes eggs or not based on if at least 50% of their answers are yes or true.

```
Console.WriteLine ("This quiz will find out if you like eggs");

Console.WriteLine ("Do you like ketchup? (yes/no)");
string quiz1 = (Console.ReadLine());
bool quiza1 = (quiz1.Contains("yes"));

Console.WriteLine ("Do you like bread? (yes/no)");
string quiz2 = (Console.ReadLine());
bool quiza2 = (quiz2.Contains("yes"));

Console.WriteLine ("Do you like to read? (yes/no)");
string quiz3 = (Console.ReadLine());
bool quiza3 = (quiz3.Contains("yes"));

Console.WriteLine ("Do you like soda? (yes/no)");
string quiz4 = (Console.ReadLine());
bool quiza4 = (quiz4.Contains("yes"));

if (quiza1 == true && quiza2 == true || quiza1 == true && quiza3 == true || quiza1 == true && quiza4 == true || quiza2 == true && quiza3 == true || quiza2 == true && quiza4 == true || quiza3 == true && quiza4 == true)
{
    Console.WriteLine ("You probably like eggs");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine ("I don't think you like eggs");
}
```

I'm specifically looking to replace the `if` statement with something more compact.

Comment: To start, (quiza1 == true && quiza2 == true) is the same as (quiza1 && quiza2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can count the number of yes answer and use this condition:

```
int countyes  = 0;

Console.WriteLine ("Do you like ketchup? (yes/no)");
string quiz1 = (Console.ReadLine());
if (quiz1.Contains("yes"))
    countyes++;
//repeat for all questions
if (countyes >= 2)
    Console.WriteLine ("You probably like eggs");
else
    Console.WriteLine ("I don't think you like eggs");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do everything in a loop and just count the number of those which answer contains "yes":

```
string[] quizzes = new string[]
{
    "Do you like ketchup? (yes/no)",
    "Do you like bread? (yes/no)",
    "Do you like to read? (yes/no)",
    "Do you like soda? (yes/no)"
}

int truecount = 0;
foreach(var quiz in quizzes)
{
    Console.WriteLine (quiz);
    if(Console.ReadLine().ToLower().Contains("yes"))
        truecount++;
}

if(truecount > quizzes.Length / 2) // here it is your choice to use > or >= or even more cases like if(truecount == quizzes.Length) you love eggs else if ....
{
  Console.WriteLine ("You probably like eggs");
}
else
{
  Console.WriteLine ("I don't think you like eggs");
}
```